# Filtering an Observable from Angular Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have seen some answers to this that apply the filter to the database call. I only need to call the database once but can't work out how to filter the array that is inside the observable returned by Firebase.

I have 2 select boxes with a list of tags. I want to get the whole set of items from Firestore and store it in the items Observable. Then when one of the select boxes changes I want to filter that observable so only the items with those tags are shown.

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
  selectedTag1;
  selectedTag2;

  filteredItems: Observable<any[]>;

  tagName1 = ['', 'TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG3', 'TAG4'];
  tagName2 = ['', 'TAG5', 'TAG6', 'TAG7',

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
  this.items = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredItems = this.items.pipe(
      map((arr => arr.filter(item =>
        item.tags.some(s => s === this.selectedTag1) &&
        item.tags.some(s => s === this.selectedTag2))
        )));
  }
```

I get no items at all showing on my template. When I change the selectedTag using the select box. I also get no filtering of the items. Can somebody suggest how I do this correctly. I need the selectBoxes to filter if only one has a value or if both have a value.

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTag1">
  <option  *ngFor="let item of tagName1">{{ item }}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTag2">
  <option  *ngFor="let item of tagName2">{{ item }}</option>
</select>

<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async">
    {{item.name}}
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let tags of item.tags">
        {{tags}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**ITEMS**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Item 1",
    "tags": [
      "TAG1",
      "TAG4",
      "TAG5",
      "TAG6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Item 2",
    "tags": [
      "TAG2",
      "TAG3",
      "TAG5",
      "TAG7",
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried to add a function which runs when the select box is changed.

```
selectChanges() {
    this.filteredItems = this.items.pipe(
      map((arr => {
        console.log(arr);
        console.log(this.selectedTag1);
        arr.filter(item => {
        console.log(item.tags);
        item.tags.some(s => s === this.selectedTag1);} );
      })));
  }
```

Yet I am still not getting any filtered results.

Comment: post your html as well, also, can you log on what you are getting on `items`

Comment: Added html and Items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already guessed, you should not filter when selected tags is undefined or empty. Just tweak your filtering logic as shown below:

```js
  filter() {
    this.filteredItems = this.items.pipe(
      map(arr =>
        arr.filter(item => {
          // return true if selectedTag1 or selectedTag2 is empty

          const matchesForTagName1 = this.selectedTag1
            ? item.tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag1) >= 0
            : true;
          const matchesForTagName2 = this.selectedTag2
            ? item.tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag2) >= 0
            : true;
          return matchesForTagName1 && matchesForTagName2;
        })
      )
    );
  }
```

You can view the complete example in Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1wkrf).

Comment: Thanks for this but the stackblitz is not filtering the items...

Comment: @Bwizard What do you mean by it is not filtering the items? It works for me. [Image](https://imgur.com/5dey7Zu).

Comment: I'm sorry but I've tried it in 2 browsers and it does not work. I'm not sure why. Here is a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kag0wo8i7z0stfj/Screenshot%202020-03-02%20at%2018.16.03.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Bwizard Updated the stackblitz app. Tested in Chrome and it is working now. Previously it was working fine with Firefox. Wierd broswer implementations.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your time!